# Xampp - MySql shutdown - Not working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I updated the MySQL version the correct way, however when clicking to start running it from the error and does not start.

Now I followed following points to install the same:

Install MySQL to `C:\TEMP`.
Make old installation folder to mysql_old.
copy the following folders "`bin, include, lib, share, support-files`" to `xamp\mysql\` folder. I didn't copy the data folder
Copied my.ini file from old installation to new installation in `xamp\mysql\bin\` folder
Copied the old data folder to new MySQL folder

Report Xampp

```
11:53:07  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:53:07  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:53:07  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:53:07  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:53:07  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:53:07  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:53:07  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Log MySQL Error:

```
2017-12-15T13:53:02.700418Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-12-15T13:53:02.700418Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-12-15T13:53:02.700418Z 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.20) starting as process 7764 ..
```

my.ini

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1



# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
#key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to start your mysql on diffrent port for example `3307`